# TextField shortcuts in NSWindow created programmatically vs SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, textfield, nswindow

I'm having a issue with a simple SwiftUI view containing a `TextField`.

If the `View` is inside a `SwiftUI App > Scene > WindowGroup`, the `TextField` in the view behave as expected and I can use shortcuts inside the `TextField` like `Command+a` to select all the text in it or `copy/past`.

If the `View` is inside a `NSHostingView` set as the `contentView` of a `NSWindow` created programmatically, my `TextField` doesn't accept shortcuts using the `Command` key. I can still type text or use shortcuts with `CTRL` but with `Command` the bell ring and nothing happens.

Here is the code for the working version:

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("My textfield", text: $text).padding()
    }
}

@main
struct TestCoreDataSwiftApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MyView()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the not working version:

```swift
import Foundation
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

let app = NSApplication.shared
let delegate = AppDelegate()
app.delegate = delegate

_ = NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)

struct MyView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("My textfield", text: $text).padding()
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    private var window: NSWindow?
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        window = NSWindow()
        window?.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: MyView())
        window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        window?.makeFirstResponder(nil)
    }
}
```

**[EDIT]**

I did more tests.

If everything is created with Interface Builder (drag and drop a `NSTextField` inside a `NSView`), it also works as expected.

If we create a `NSView` programmatically and add a `NSTextField`, here again it doesn't work:

```swift
    // Not working code
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) 
    {
        NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
        window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 400, y: 400, width: 400, height: 100), styleMask: [.miniaturizable, .closable, .resizable, .titled], backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.center()
        window.title = "Title"
        window.contentView = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
        let textField = NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 60))
        window.contentView?.addSubview(textField)
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }
```

I suspect it's something related to the focus or the `firstResponder` but I'm unable to make it work. Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, those shortcuts are related to the application menu (`NSMenu`). They don't exist by default without it.
So, if the application doesn't have the `Edit` menu where all this shortcuts are defined, they are simply not available in the `TextField`.

In the various cases where it works, it's because both the default IB project and the Swift UI project add this menu by default.

It's not a matter of `firstResponder` in this case.

In order to make this work, the solutions are:

1. Add the `Edit` menu in the application with the shortcuts (doesn't work if the menu is hidden).
2. Manage shortcuts programmatically as suggested by VonC

```
class NSHostingViewShortcuts<Content>: NSHostingView<Content> where Content : View {
    override func performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
        if event.modifierFlags.contains(.command) {
            let shortcuts = [
                "a": #selector(NSStandardKeyBindingResponding.selectAll(_:)),
                "x": #selector(NSText.cut(_:)),
                "c": #selector(NSText.copy(_:)),
                "v": #selector(NSText.paste(_:))
            ]
            if event.characters != nil && shortcuts[event.characters!] != nil {
                NSApp.sendAction(shortcuts[event.characters!]!, to: nil, from: nil)
                return true
            }
        }
        
        return super.performKeyEquivalent(with: event)
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch, upvoted. I have edited my answer to expand on my original proposition.

Answer (score 1):

In the working version, SwiftUI handles the keyboard shortcuts natively.
However, in the non-working version, [`NSWindow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow) is not configured to pass on keyboard shortcuts like `Command+a` to the SwiftUI view hosted inside the [`NSHostingView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/nshostingview/).

That means you need to make sure your `NSWindow` is properly forwarding these events to the `NSHostingView`.
A possible approach would be to subclass `NSHostingView` and override the [`performKeyEquivalent(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/nshostingview/performkeyequivalent(with:)/) method to manually handle these shortcuts.

```swift
import Foundation
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

let app = NSApplication.shared
let delegate = AppDelegate()
app.delegate = delegate

_ = NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)

struct MyView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("My textfield", text: $text).padding()
    }
}

class CustomNSHostingView<Content>: NSHostingView<Content> where Content : View {
    override func performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
        // Handle Command key shortcuts here
        // Example: Command + a
        if event.modifierFlags.contains(.command) {
            if event.characters == "a" {
                // Do something for Command + a
                return true
            }
            // Add other command key shortcuts as needed
        }

        return super.performKeyEquivalent(with: event)
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    private var window: NSWindow?
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        window = NSWindow()
        window?.contentView = CustomNSHostingView(rootView: MyView())
        window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        window?.makeFirstResponder(nil)
    }
}
```

You would need to expand this to include other shortcuts like copy and paste.

---

From [Vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10376267/vincent)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77814601/6309), the suggestion to subclass `NSHostingView` and override the `performKeyEquivalent(with:)` method was helpful: it allows for direct control over how keyboard events are handled when the standard Edit menu is not available or when the application's structure does not support these shortcuts.

Overriding `performKeyEquivalent(with:)` provided a way to intercept keyboard events and implement custom behavior, which is essential for handling shortcuts like `Command+a`.

I missed the presence or absence of an Edit menu, which impacts the availability of these shortcuts. And I missed the specific mapping of these actions to their respective selectors, which is crucial for mimicking the behavior of the Edit menu.
Using `NSApp.sendAction` to send the actions to the responder chain is a key detail for implementing these shortcuts.

If I combines my initial approach and the OP's, I can still subclass `NSHostingView`, override `performKeyEquivalent(with:)`, and map keyboard shortcuts to the corresponding `NSMenu` actions using `NSApp.sendAction`.

```swift
import Foundation
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

let app = NSApplication.shared
let delegate = AppDelegate()
app.delegate = delegate

_ = NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)

struct MyView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("My textfield", text: $text).padding()
    }
}

class CustomNSHostingView<Content>: NSHostingView<Content> where Content : View {
    override func performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
        if event.modifierFlags.contains(.command), let characters = event.characters {
            let shortcuts: [String: Selector] = [
                "a": #selector(NSStandardKeyBindingResponding.selectAll(_:)),
                "x": #selector(NSText.cut(_:)),
                "c": #selector(NSText.copy(_:)),
                "v": #selector(NSText.paste(_:))
            ]

            if let action = shortcuts[characters] {
                NSApp.sendAction(action, to: nil, from: nil)
                return true
            }
        }

        return super.performKeyEquivalent(with: event)
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    private var window: NSWindow?
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        window = NSWindow()
        window?.contentView = CustomNSHostingView(rootView: MyView())
        window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        window?.makeFirstResponder(nil)
    }
}
```

By subclassing `NSHostingView` and handling the key equivalents within it, that allows for easy extension or modification of shortcut handling, making it more adaptable to different contexts or additional shortcuts.

Comment: I did more tests (see my edit). With Interface Builder without Swift, it's working. If we do it programmatically without Swift (by adding an `NSTextField` inside a `NSView`), here again, it doesn't work. The code to handle this shortcuts must be somewhere.